# val() is showing empty string when it actually contains a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My generated code looks like this in chrome's developer tools:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="LiveAgentStatusField" value="Online" >
                Online
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Please note that this html code is generated by salesforce and I don't have much control over this except the span.

My jQuery code:

```
$(".LiveAgentStatusField").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).val() === 'online' || $(this).val() === 'Online') {
        $(this).css("color", "#0EBE5E");
    } else if ($(this).val() === 'offline' || $(this).val() === 'Offline') {
        $(this).css("color", "#ccc");
    }
});
```

There are two wield things happening to me:

1. When I am using `.LiveAgentStatusField`, it works pretty fine. But when I was using `span.LiveAgentStatusField`, it doesn't even go into the if code during debugging.
2. Although the value of the span tag should have a value of `'Online'`, `$(this).val()` is actually `""` during debugging. I added a line under this to catch the `val() === ""` branch and made sure this is pointing to the right element.

Actually, I have already resolved my code issue with using `.html()`. But I am quite keen to find out why it is acting strange.

Comment: use `$(this).html()` or `$(this).text()`

Comment: value is typically for form controls. Use `data-value` and `$(this).data('value")` instead

Comment: Stackoverflow users are quite cynical these days. If you look at the all questions board there are fewer questions with positive mark than negative ones, which makes me think there are some professional critics who has nothing to do other than giving negative marks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.val()` method only works with form elements. If you want to get the value of the `value` attribute on a non-form element, use:

```
$(this).attr('value');
```

However, as others have noted, it is preferable to use a `data-` prefix (e.g. `data-value`), as this is standards compliant. The `value` attribute is only valid on certain elements and it is certainly not valid on `span`s.

If use a `data-value` attribute, you can access it using `.data('value')` and then your code becomes:

```
$(".LiveAgentStatusField").each(function(index) {
    var value = $(this).data("value").toLowerCase();

    if (value === 'online') {
        $(this).css("color", "#0EBE5E");
    } else if (value === 'offline') {
        $(this).css("color", "#ccc");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually `value` is invalid attribute here. Commonly It is used for inputs in form. In your case .html() is enough

EDIT: jQuery has [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function for removing trailing whitespaces

```
var spanVal = $(this).html().toLowerCase(); // you don't need to call html() each time
spanVal = $.trim(spanVal);
if (spanVal === 'online') ... // do all the stuff
```

Yes, you can use `data-value` attribute and get it with `data('value')` function, but in  your case more obvious solution is to use class you already have:

```
  <span class="LiveAgentStatusField online">
                                        Online
            </span>
```

then all jquery code will look like

```
$(".LiveAgentStatusField.online").css("color", "#0EBE5E");
$(".LiveAgentStatusField.offline").css("color", "#ccc");
```

jQuery will do `each` loop and all other stuff for you. Also I don't know why you are making it deferred, but if you want to make it at once - just use css

```
.LiveAgentStatusField.online { color: #0EBE5E; }
```

Comment: have to trim html though or won't get the match expected

Comment: the class method is a lot cleaner

Answer (score 2):

I would use `data` attributes instead

HTML

```
<span class="LiveAgentStatusField" data-value="Online" >
```

JS

```
$(this).data("value")
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/okyhykdu/)

Comment: Good answer. It would help to elaborate on why this is preferable to using the 'value' attribute (which isn't a valid attribute for `span`), and how data attributes are the standardized way of incorporating meta-data into markup. Code only answers tend be less favorably viewed, and aren't as clear.